# Why is the Object class using mostly static methods while the Array class is mostly having instance methods?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am wondering why, when working with arrays I usually work with instance methods such as `.split`, `.indexOf`, `.map` while when working with objects, I mostly use static methods on the `Object` class?

I count 21 static methods for the [Object class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), and just 3 for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), of which 2 are concerned with creation rather than manipulation.

The only explanation I can come up with, is that since everything inherits from Object in JS, the designers wanted to keep those Object objects as lightweight as possible.

Comment: that's wrong, Arrays can also have  Objects usage

Comment: Quite the contrary - not everything inherits from object and static methods can be applied to objects created from `null`, consider e.g. `a = Object.create(null); Object.seal(a)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only explanation I can come up with, is that since everything inherits from Object in JS, the designers wanted to keep those Object objects as lightweight as possible.

That's it exactly. You don't want to fill up `Object.prototype` with a bunch of methods, because they'd be on **everything** that's an object (or at least, everything that's an object that inherits from `Object.prototype`, which all objects do by default though you can prevent it with `Object.create`).

There's a second, more subtle reason: Because you don't want basic operations altered by objects in the general case. That's one reason you see people avoiding using the `hasOwnProperty` method on an object and instead using it directly from `Object.prototype`:

```
if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "name")) {
    // ...
}
```

The author of the code above wanted to avoid the possibility that `hasOwnProperty` had been redefined for `obj` such that it would lie. :-)

```js
const obj = {
    hasOwnProperty() {
        return true;
    }
};

console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("foo"));                        // true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "foo")); // false, which is correct
```